# Using CurrentRoleInstance.Id to run a task in just one instance

Tags: azure

In a context where you are deploying a web role over multiple instances and require to schedule a task that should be done by one instance only (like sending an email to the site admin with some stats), how reliable is it to use `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id` in order to make the task run on one instance only (like only running it if the Id finishes with `IN_0`) ?
If anyone has ever done this, I'd be interested in his feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't use instance ID. What happens if instance 0 gets rebooted (which happens at least once per month)? Now your scheduler or task-runner is offline.

An alternate solution is to use a type of mutex that spans instances. The one I'm thinking of is a blob lease. You can actually acquire a lease on a blob for writing (and there can only be one lease-holder). You could attempt to get a blob lease before running a task. If you get it, run task. If you don't, don't run it.

A slight variation: In a thread (let's say started from your `Run()` method), attempt to acquire a lease and if successful, launch a scheduler task (maybe a thread or something). If you cannot acquire the lease, sleep for a minute and try again. Eventually, the instance with the lease will be rebooted (or it'll disappear for some other reason). After a few seconds, another instance will acquire the abandoned lease and start up a new scheduler task.

Steve Marx wrote a [blog post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases) about concurrency using leases. Tyler Doerksen also has a [good post](http://tylerdev.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/intermediate-azure-storage-blob-leasing/) about leases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already went through smarx's blog post. Still, I don't completely get your point about the instance being rebooted. After the reboot, it will still have the same instance ID, right ?
If so, it would be possible to cope with the situation when it gets rebooted exactly when the task should be ran (by running it just after the reboot for example).

Comment: My point is that you always want a scheduler running. If you depend on a specific instance, you're guaranteed to have downtime. Also: what happens if you scale *down*? You cannot specify which instance to remove. What happens if the removed instance is the one you refer to all the time?

Comment: True. I'll implement that blob lease option. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

yes you can use the InstanceId if needed specificaly

```
 <Startup>
  <Task commandLine="StartUpTasks\WindowService\InstallWindowService.bat"  executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" >
  <Environment>
    <Variable name="InstanceId">
        <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/@id"/>
    </Variable>
   </Environment>
  </Task>
 </Startup>
```

it will be of following form

```
<deployment Id>.<Application Name>.<Role Name>_IN_<index>
 Example mostly MyRole_IN_0, MyRole_IN_1
```

Access the environmet variable in batch file like this

```
 %InstanceId%
```

You cane then use substring or last index of _ to get the index from InstanceId.
if this instance having index 0  will have the same index even after a reboot.

More Details
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cclayton/archive/2012/05/17/windows-azure-start-up-tasks-part-2.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh404006.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have some block of execution code only run once if you have multiple instances, by for example checking the ID of the current role instance you are executing at.

You could achieve the same result with other solutions, but those might require some more work, like decoupling the task from your instance